# Azure Scale Set: NAT rule not working

Tags: node.js, powershell, azure

I have created a `VMSS` with a load balancer (LB).

Now there is only one VM with a `nodeJs` application running in and listening on port 80.

I have allowed port access on VM Firewall (inbound + outbound).

I have added an Inbound LB `NAT` rules on port 80 through the portal. However after saving, it does not show up.

Now I could not access my application with the Public IP or DNS name.

What is wrong with my approach ?

How can I do this with the portal or the powershell ?

I would not like to recreate the scale set.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally make it works through the portal. In fact the scale set has an Inbound NAT Rule and a load balancing rules. Allowing firewall port access and NAT rules are Ok for this scenario but not enough , a Load balancing rule on port 80 needs to be added.  Before the load balancing rule is added a probe should be added first.
In short here are the steps:

1. **Firewall access on port 80**
2. **Inbound NAT Rule (under load balancer) access on port 80**
3. **Probe access on port 80**
4. **Load balancing rule on port 80 (need a probe)**